# Multisets in Agda

Tags: agda

I am new to Agda, and I am wondering which package shall I install for multisets? I am aware of the multisets in Cubical Agda, but I may not want to go that far at the moment.

I tried to find packages on google and chagpt but neither give satisfying and answer. I just need a pointer to the sepcific package(s) that provide multisets and basic manipulations on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with basic Agda, you will not find a *type* of multisets because multisets are only representable using quotients, which basic Agda does not have.

Instead, I think you want to work with (the *setoid* of) lists up to permutation. The standard library provides a (IME difficult to work with) definition of permutations at [Data.List.Relation.Binary.Permutation.Homogeneous](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.List.Relation.Binary.Permutation.Homogeneous.html), and you can explore that part of the library to see what operations it provides (probably in `.Properties` files). I know of two other ways to represent permutations. The first (“functional”) way is to say that the membership relations of the two lists are in bijection with each other. Formally, `xs ≈ ys = ∀ z → (z ∈ xs) ↔ (z ∈ ys)`, where `_↔_` is defined somewhere in the `Function` hierarchy and `_∈_` is in the `Data.List.Membership` hierarchy. The second (“Prolog”) way is to use definitions like this:

```
open import Data.List

data Insert {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) : List A → List A → Set a where
  here : ∀ {xs} → Insert x xs (x ∷ xs)
  there : ∀ {y ys zs} → Insert x ys zs → Insert x (y ∷ ys) (y ∷ zs)

data Permutation {a} {A : Set a} : List A → List A → Set a where
  [] : Permutation [] []
  _∷_ : ∀ {x xs ys xys} → Insert x ys xys → Permutation xs ys → Permutation (x ∷ xs) xys
```

Of these two ways, probably the first is quicker to get going with, because you can reuse facts about bijections. However, I think the second is more expedient in many cases when you have the basic definitions in place, particularly if you're working with standard library definitions like `Data.List.Relation.Ternary.Interleaving` and `Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise`. I'm not aware of any implementations of these two which is maintained in a library, but you might find useful pieces in the standard library.